# What is special about the SSDs in MacBook Pro mid 2015?

Tags: hard-drive, mac, ssd, macbook-pro

I have been checking out several resources online (iFixit, MacRumours and Apple Discussion Forums) about the potential for an SSD upgrade on 2015 model MBPs (perhaps not now, but in the future).

The claim is that there are no compatible 3rd party components and that one needs to find an OEM piece that's likely pulled from another MBP (for instance a factory model).

I am not sure I fully grasp the difference between the existing M.2 form factor SSDs and the one in my MBP. Is it the just about the read/write speed or will none of the commercially available M.2 SSDs fit physically?